# Windows 7 Auto login

Tags: windows-7

Is it possible to configure windows 7 such that it will always auto login as a particular user - this includes when coming out of sleep or hibernation or after a remote desktop connection has been made - ie avoiding the console is locked message

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. From the start menu, in the Run... dialog, type `control userpasswords2`
2. On the User Accounts dialog that opens, select the user that you want to automatically log in
3. Uncheck the option `Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer.`
4. Click apply. You will be prompted for the password for the selected user. Click Ok, Click Ok again.

Now whenever your pc starts, the selected user will automatically be logged in. As for screen locking, RDP, etc., you will need to set those options in the appropriate locations.

Answer (score 1):

Joe Internet's solution works for regular autologin. You cannot set it to autologin at the workstation locked screen, but you can prevent the computer from ever locking. There are several group policy settings you can use for this - you could either completely disable locking the computer (`User Settings/Administrative Templates/System/Ctrl+Alt+Del Options`), or set it to not lock when resuming from standby/hibernate (`User Settings/Administrative Templates/System/Power Management`) or from the screensaver (`User Settings/Administrative Templates/Control Panel/Display|Password Protect The Screensaver`). This will keep the computer from ever locking, except when resuming from an RDP session. I don't think there is any way to automatically log back in from a disconnected session.

Answer (score 0):

You can use see this [article](http://forum.sysinternals.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=20245&PN=2) and this [one](http://www.logonexpert.com/freeautologon.html) for a beginning. Hope this helps.